# I need to compare 2 tables in SQL Server Database, and Create a new Column with "Paid" or "NotPaid"

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am not too sure that I will be able to do this in SQL but I am trying to compare a column in one table to a column in another.

So I have a table Named "`PolicyList`" with all my data.

I have another table name "`PolicyWithPayments`" with only the certain records in this one.

I would like to compare these two like this:

```
**PolicyList**           **PolicyWithPayments**           **HitRWithPay**
 *PolicyNumber*             *PolicyNumber*                 *PaidNotPaid*
  1212                        1212                           Paid 
  2323                        3434                           NotPaid
  3434                                                       Paid
```

I have the data in the first two columns, but I need the third column, PaidNotPaid , In my new table to be populated based on if the number exists in PolicyWithPayments.

If the Number is in `PolicyWithPayment = "Paid"`

If the number is not in PolicyWithPayments, but is in `Policy List = "NotPaid"`

If you need any other information or anything Is not clear please let me know.

Thank you!!

Thank you Hari! I obviously did not know what I was doing....

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `left join`:

```
select pl.*,
       (case when pwp.PolicyNumber is not null then 'Paid' else 'NotPaid' end) as PaidNotPaid
from PolicyList pl left join
     PolicyWithPayments pwp
     on pwp.PolicyNumber = pl.PolicyNumber;
```

That said, I actually prefer using `exists` for this purpose:

```
select pl.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from PolicyWithPayments pwp where pwp.PolicyNumber = pl.PolicyNumber)
             then 'Paid' else 'NotPaid'
        end) as PaidNotPaid
from PolicyList pl;
```

The advantage is that this will not inadvertently multiply the number of rows, if there are duplicates in the second table.

Comment: Thank You so much Gordon Linoff!!!! I owe you my life it worked perfectly.